# Electrum two factor authentication

Tags: wallet, electrum, two-factor-authentication

In the Electrum wallet for pc, it is possible to modify a wallet from normal password to 2fA (two factor authentication ) without creating a new wallet?

Also, the fee for the 2fA it's billed only when sending funds from the 2fA wallet to outside, and not when we receive, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the Electrum wallet for pc, it is possible to modify a wallet from
>   normal password to 2fA (two factor authentication ) without creating a
>   new wallet?

No, it is not possible to add two-factor authentication to an existing wallet. these are two different wallet types.

> the fee for the 2fA it's billed only when sending funds from the 2fA
>   wallet to outside, and not when we receive, right?

The sender always pays the fee.